# Why does wrapping a ReactiveSwift MutableProperty in a Property cause a leak?

Tags: ios, swift, memory-leaks, reactive-cocoa, reactive-swift

Here's a Swift class that uses ReactiveSwift, wrapping a `MutableProperty` in a `Property`, and adding a subscription to that `Property` in a `ScopedDisposable`:

```
class Leaker {
    let mutableProperty = MutableProperty<Int>(0)

    var wrapperProperty: Property<Int> {
        return Property(self.mutableProperty)
    }

    private var disposable: ScopedDisposable<AnyDisposable>?

    init() {
        let disposable = CompositeDisposable()

        disposable += self.wrapperProperty.producer
            .startWithValues { value in
                print("\(value)")
            }

        self.disposable = ScopedDisposable(disposable)
    }
}
```

If I give another class a property of type `Leaker?`, and then set it using `self.leaker = Leaker()`, this creates a leak. By "creates a leak," I mean it sets off the Leaks instrument, showing a leaked object labeled `Malloc 32 Bytes`, with a stack trace that includes `Leaker.init()` calling `Leaker.wrapperProperty.getter`.

Why does this leak? I'm finding it hard to understand exactly what is causing the memory allocated here to never be released.

Some other facts that might be useful:

- This doesn't leak if I subscribe to `mutableProperty` directly
- This doesn't leak if I wrap `mutableProperty` in a lazy property instead of a computed property
- This doesn't leak if I create a temporary `Leaker`, e.g. `let _ = Leaker()`

Comment: Which version of ReactiveSwift are you using? [There used to be a false-positive memory leak issue that has since been fixed](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveSwift/pull/355).

Comment: Thanks! We were on ReactiveSwift 2.0. Will try the new version.

Comment: Looks like it was [fixed in 2.0](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveSwift/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200-alpha1), so maybe that's not the issue.

Comment: I can see the leak as well. But I don't have to free the `Leaker` object. It even shows up if I keep a reference to the `Leaker` object. Stack trace shows `Property.init(unsafeProducer: SignalProducer<Value, NoError>)` as the source.

Answer (score 3):

I tried, but was not able to reproduce the memory leak. I've used your exact `Leaker` class with this code:

```
final class OtherClass {
  let leaker: Leaker?

  init() {
    self.leaker = Leaker()
  }
}

var otherClass: OtherClass? = OtherClass()

var mutablePropertyCompleted = false
otherClass!.leaker!.mutableProperty.producer.startWithCompleted {
  mutablePropertyCompleted = true
}

var wrappedPropertyCompleted = false
otherClass!.leaker!.wrapperProperty.producer.startWithCompleted {
  wrappedPropertyCompleted = true
}

otherClass = nil

if(!mutablePropertyCompleted) {
  print("LEAK")
}

if(!wrappedPropertyCompleted) {
  print("LEAK")
}
```

One thing to note is that `MutableProperty` sends `completed` in its `deinit` method, so it should be possible to detect a leak the way I did here.

But just to be sure I also profiled this with the memory leaks instrument which detected nothing.

Since you mentioned some specific circumstances in which this does not leak for you it might just be that the way I'm trying to reproduce the issue is wrong, maybe you can post a complete example?

Anyway, I don't see an error in the example you posted, so either this is a bug in ReactiveSwift, or its a false positive by the profiler (which has happened with ReactiveSwift before as jjoelson pointed out in his comment)